# GeoJSON, circlemarkers using Leaflet OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier plugin?

Tags: leaflet, markers, plugins

I am wondering if I can use the Leaflet [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet) plugin with my circlemarkers.

I've loaded a GeoJSON file and added circlemarkers using;

```
var gj = L.geoJson(route, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
 },
 onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
 }).addTo(map);
```

I followed the OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier example but I cannot understand how to combine my circlemarkers with the plugin.

I am guessing that changing;

```
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);

 }
```

to something like

```
oms.addMarker(marker);
```

(Leaflet OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier is a port of the original library for the Google Maps API)

Comment: Your link to github looks wrong. I think you meant https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier is a plugin designed for the `L.Marker` class in Leaflet. Thus, it only accepts an `L.Marker` object and can't handle `L.circleMarker` properly, since it's based on the [`L.Circle`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle) objects which is based on [`L.Path`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path). Credit for pointing this out goes to @FranceImage.

You can't use the `L.circleMarker` layer with the spiderfier plugin, it will be glitchy (http://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/qzdr2w73/). However, you can convert your GeoJSON data to traditional markers with the `L.Marker` object. You can customize your marker icon to resemble to the circleMarker object (http://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/qzdr2w73/4/).

To do this easily, Leaflet offers a [`L.DivIcon`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon) style which can be customized with pure CSS, you won't need an image. To make orange circles with solid border in CSS, the code will look like the following:

```
.mydivicon{
    width: 12px
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #ff7800;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    opacity: 0.85
}
```

The most important part is the `border-radius` property. It will round your shape at the corners. To create a regular circle with it, you have to calculate the radius with the border. The formula is `width / 2 + border * 4` if `width = height`. After you created the CSS, you have to make a `L.DivIcon` object to be used with `L.Marker`:

```
var icon = new L.divIcon({className: 'mydivicon'});
```

When rendering the GeoJSON data to the map object, use `L.Marker` instead of `L.circleMarker` with the previously created icon:

```
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {
        icon: icon});
```

Now to use OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier properly: you have to create an OMS instance before adding the GeoJSON data:

```
var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);
```

After, you have to add each marker to the OMS object, so the built-in renderer can use them. To do this, use the `onEachFeature` method of `L.geoJson`:

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, latlng) {
    oms.addMarker(latlng);
}
```

Finally, create an event associated with the OMS object and the markers it contains and add popup content to the markers. Note: if you don't add some markers to the OMS object, it won't apply the spiderfy effect on them. Also, the popup content in my case is in the [GeoJSON data](http://leafletjs.com/examples/sample-geojson.js) (properties -> popupContent).

```
var popup = new L.Popup();
oms.addListener('click', function(marker) {
    popup.setContent(marker.feature.properties.popupContent);
    popup.setLatLng(marker.getLatLng());
    map.openPopup(popup);
});
```

Final note: markers created with `L.DivIcon` will be rendered as individual `div` objects instead of canvas or SVG. If you use a lot of points (around thousand or more) the rendering process will be painfully slow if the browser doesn't crash. To avoid it at masses of points like that, use OMS with other strategies (clusters, bounding box, etc.).

Comment: You're right. L.CircleMarker is a L.Path not a L.Marker

Comment: Very good solution. To be picky I would add that it lacks two semicolons in the css class (width and opacity).